# Is there a purpose for the Planet Scanning meters?

Tags: mass-effect-2

When scanning a planet, the UI includes meters for each of the resources you might collect.  The bars in each of these meters seem to max out when you've collected about 25,000 of the given resource.  However, I've been able to continue collecting those resources far beyond the point of maxing out the meters - I currently have well over 50,000 Palladium.

So far, I haven't noticed any adverse effects of "overstocking" on resources like this.  Is there something I'm missing, or do these meters really serve no purpose aside from simple UI fluff?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the meters serve no purpose. You can collect as many resources as you find on the planets. Maybe Bioware once planned a maximum capacity for resources but removed that later on.

Answer (score -1):

I have a hypothesis that the meters represent the maximum amount that you can carry over to ME3, but I haven't tested it yet. I'm going to on my current playthrough.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).